# Zoom in layer with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am working on creating a plugin on QGIS 3.10. This plugin loads two layers in my QGIS project. I would like to zoom in the layer extent of `AEE_layer`. Unfortunately despite the code that specifies to zoom the canvas on the `AEE_layer` extent, it does not work. The canvas systematically zooms in on the extent of all the layers that are loaded in my project.

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
                
project.write('C:/CartoIni/Projet/Projet.qgs')

groupe_aire = root.addGroup("Aires d'étude")

AEE_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Data/AEE.shp", 'AEE','ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(AEE_layer, False)
groupe_aire.addLayer(AEE_layer)

reg_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Data/REGION.shp", 'Limites régionales','ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(reg_layer, False)
groupe_aire.addLayer(reg_layer)

extent = AEE_layer.extent()
canvas.setExtent(extent)
canvas.refresh()
```

Comment: Try by replacing : `canvas = iface.mapCanvas()`, and welcome to GIS SE !

Comment: With iface.mapCanvas() the problem is the same

Comment: What is the result of `AEE_layer.extent()` ?

Comment: the result of `AEE_layer.extent()` : `<QgsRectangle: 610783.06441810820251703 6745293.08760993927717209, 623023.31778933946043253 6757083.76099352352321148>`

Comment: With a canvas CRS configured to Lambert 93 (EPSG: 2154), I tried in the QGIS Python console `iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(QgsRectangle(610783.06441810820251703, 6745293.08760993927717209, 623023.31778933946043253, 6757083.76099352352321148))` and it zooms perfectly to the Orléans - Olivet area. Check your canvas coordinate system.

Comment: I tried also in the QGIS Python console. I have the same result as you but when i load my plugin in QGIS it doesn't work

Comment: is the layer loaded in the QGIS main canvas with your plugin ?

Comment: I uptaded my code in the post above. I use QgsLayerTreeMapCanvas() when I load my project. Is this the right way to go ?

Comment: like my first comment, change your 2nd line into `canvas = iface.mapCanvas()` (even if it didn't produce the good result now, because here, you create your own canvas and you don't display it).

Comment: I change my second line. How can I display the canvas created in this case ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122540/discussion-between-mathys-wohl-and-j-monticolo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to load layers and before set the new extent, tell to your canvas to wait before rendering.
An important thing too is to set your project or canvas CRS. In the code, I left the two but only one work.

Try the code below :

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

# modifications ##
crs_l93 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:2154")
project.setCrs(crs_l93)
canvas.setDestinationCrs(crs_l93)
# ################

project.write('C:/CartoIni/Projet/Projet.qgs')

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()  # add the root object, as your original code
groupe_aire = root.addGroup("Aires d'étude")

AEE_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Data/AEE.shp", 'AEE','ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(AEE_layer, False)
groupe_aire.addLayer(AEE_layer)

reg_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Data/REGION.shp", 'Limites régionales','ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(reg_layer, False)
groupe_aire.addLayer(reg_layer)

canvas.waitWhileRendering()  # modification here
extent = AEE_layer.extent()
canvas.setExtent(extent)
canvas.refresh()
```

| **EDIT**: if the first code doesn't work |
| --- |

You can set the extent once the canvas is refreshed a first time :

```py
def set_aee_extent():
    extent = AEE_layer.extent()
    canvas.setExtent(extent)
    # disconnect the signal to avoid calling set_aee_extent again
    canvas.mapCanvasRefreshed.disconnect(set_aee_extent)
    canvas.refresh()

project = QgsProject.instance()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

# modifications ##
crs_l93 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:2154")
project.setCrs(crs_l93)
canvas.setDestinationCrs(crs_l93)
# ################

project.write("C:/CartoIni/Projet/Projet.qgs")

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()  # add the root object, as your original code
groupe_aire = root.addGroup("Aires d'étude")

AEE_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Data/AEE.shp", 'AEE','ogr')
reg_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Data/REGION.shp", 'Limites régionales','ogr')

canvas.mapCanvasRefreshed.connect(set_aee_extent)

canvas.setLayers([AEE_layer, reg_layer])
groupe_aire.addLayer(AEE_layer)
groupe_aire.addLayer(reg_layer)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing `QgsMapCanvas()` with `iface.mapCanvas()`

```
AEE_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/Thysma/Documents/Stage/Data/AEE.shp", 'AEE','ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(AEE_layer, False)

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
extent = AEE_layer.extent()
canvas.setExtent(extent)
canvas.refresh()
```

Check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/363373/107424